# Associating script with a button in ASP .NET MVC Razor View

Tags: jquery, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a button and a script:

```
   <script>
   function SubmitClick () {
        var pid = $(this).data('personid');
        var sid = $(this).data('surveyid');
        var url = '@Url.Action("SubmitSurvey", "Person")';
        $.post(url, { personid: pid, surveyid: sid }, function (data) {
            alert('updated');
        });
    };
</script>
```

When I click the button the script is not run/called/invoked. How to make this button invoke this script?

Full view `_Survey1.html` **this is PartialView**:

```
<script>
   function SubmitClick () {
        var pid = $(this).data('personid');
        var sid = $(this).data('surveyid');
        var url = '@Url.Action("SubmitSurvey", "Person")';
        $.post(url, { personid: pid, surveyid: sid }, function (data) {
            alert('updated');
        });
    };
</script>

@using WebApplication2.Models
@model   System.Tuple<Person, List<Survey>>

<hr />
<h1>Surveys</h1>
<input type="button" id="Coll" value="Collapse" onclick="javascript:CollapseDiv()" />
@*<p>
        Number of Surveys: @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.Item2.Count)
    </p>*@

@{int i = 1;}
@foreach (var survey in Model.Item2) {
    using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        <h2>Survey @(i)</h2>
        <p />
        @Html.EditorFor(x => survey.Questions)


        <button class='mybutton' type='button' data-personid="@Model.Item1.Id" data-surveyid="@survey.Id" onclick="javascript:SubmitClick()">Click Me</button>
    }
    i++;
    <hr style="background-color:rgb(126, 126, 126);height: 5px" />
}
<hr />
```

The `SubmitSurvey` method in `PersonController`:

```
 public void SubmitSurvey(int personId, int surveyId) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("UPDATING DATABASE");

    }
```

**The result** is that after clicking the button I get error saying that `SubmitClick`haven't been found:

[image]

Details.cshtml (the _Survey1.cshtml) is rendered inside of it.

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Person

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<script>
    function BtnOnclick() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Person/_Survey1")',
            data: {
                id: '@Model.Id'
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#divpopup').css("display", "block");
                $('#btnExpand').css("display", "none");
                $('#divpopup')[0].innerHTML = data;
            }
        });
    }
    function CollapseDiv() {
        $('#divpopup').css("display", "none");
        $('#btnExpand').css("display", "block");
    }




</script>
<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Person</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </dt>


        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CellNumber)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CellNumber)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SecondaryPhoneNumber)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SecondaryPhoneNumber)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BirthDate)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BirthDate)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Pesel)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Pesel)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Notes)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Notes)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Status.Name)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PersonalDataProcessing)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PersonalDataProcessing)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<!--BEGIN-->
<p>
    <input type="button" value="Expand" id="btnExpand"
           onclick="javascript:BtnOnclick();" />
</p>
<div id="divpopup" style="display:none">

</div>
<!--END-->

<p>@Html.ActionLink("Call Cell Phone", "Call", new { id = Model.Id, number = Model.CellNumber }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })</p>
<p> @Html.ActionLink("Call Client's Secondary Number »", "Call", new { id = Model.Id, number = Model.SecondaryPhoneNumber }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })</p>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.Id })
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

Comment: There was an answer, what happened?

Comment: Always include the `type` attribute for buttons. Different browsers use different defaults, so it may be defaulting to submit. `<button id='mybutton' type='button'>Click Me</button>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I fully updated the Original Post -> code and description. I added `type='button'` to the html. It prevented yellow screen of death, there are no runtime errors BUT nothing happens after click, there is no output on the console or anything.

Comment: Your also creating multiple buttons with the same `id` so its not going to work as you intend. I post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the script from the `foreach` loop and add a single script at the bottom of the page. In the loop, assign the values you want to pass to the post method as `data` attributes of the button so they can be accessed in the script. For example

```
@foreach (var survey in Model.Item2) {
  using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    ....
    <button class='mybutton' type='button' data-personid="@Model.Item.ID" data-surveyid="@Survey.ID">Click Me</button>
```

And the script

```
$('.mybutton').click(function() {
  var pid = $(this).data('personid');
  var sid = $(this).data('surveyid');
  var url = '@Url.Action("SubmitSurvey", "Person")';
  $.post(url, { personid: pid, surveyid: sid }, function(data) {
    alert('updated');
  });
});
```

Note: the post method should return JSON data indicating success or otherwise so you can test the result - for example `return Json(true)` or `return Json(null)`, then in the script `if(data) { alert('updated'); } else { alert('oops'); }`

Comment: I have tried exacly what you have posted. There were no errors but the java script function was never even invoked. I modified it little bit. Current code is in Original Post. I gave name to your function and added: `onclick="javascript:SubmitClick()"` to the button. This gives runtime error which says that definition of `SubmitClick` has not been found. I post in 2 minutes the screenshot in OP.

Comment: Oh my code after using your solution looked like this: http://wklej.org/id/1452605/  nothing happenned.

Comment: `_Survey1.html` ** is PartialView** and it is invoked from `Details.cshtml` postem at the bottom of OP.

Comment: I posted answer. It works but I think it is done in old style. Could you refer please?

Comment: @Yoda, The script has to be placed at the bottom of the page or wrapped in `$(document).ready`! I don't see how your 'answer' works - your hard coding the values of `personId` and `surveyId` so they are always going to have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the script in the razor block, and as possible as put all script to the bottom of the page, in order to improve the page response well.

Comment: I'll be back working in 2 hours(asked question at 2am) but the reason I put it there was that there is local variable `survey` in `foreach` loop. That is why I put it there, I don't know how to pass it as parameter to JQuery method.

Comment: OK, let's consider that refactoring submit method in javascript, then pass the item.id and survey.id as parameter to the jQuery method. It's my way for you case, you could try it once if you have convenient time.

Comment: I don't know correct syntax yet. Could you present how to do it
?

Answer (score 0):

I had to put script in the `Details.cshtml` which is master View to the `_Survey1.cshtml`(Partial View).
Also putting this script in `Details.csthml` caused that server tried to execute it when I went to `Details.cshtml`(before even I clicked a button) causing runtime error:

```
$('.mybutton').click(function() {
  var pid = $(this).data('personid');
  var sid = $(this).data('surveyid');
  var url = '@UrlAction("SubmitSurvey", "Person")';
  $.post(url, { personid: pid, surveyid: sid }, function(data) {
    alert('updated');
  });
});
```

So I changed it to:

```
  function SubmitClick(pid, sid) {     
        var url = '@Url.Action("SubmitSurvey", "Person")';
        $.post(url, { personid: pid, surveyid: sid }, function (data) {
            alert('updated' + pid + " " + sid);
        });
    }
```

I had to add parameters because without them `pid` and `sid` were undefined, even though `data-personid="@Model.Item1.Id" data-surveyid="@survey.Id"` where defined in the button.

The button looks like:

```
  <button class='mybutton' type='button' onclick="javascript:SubmitClick(@Model.Item1.Id, @survey.Id.);" >Click Me</button>
```