# Definition of Function SubmitSurvey have not been found but I defined it

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

It is literally fifth day I try to solve this.

I try to invoke a method by a button in Razor View, no redirections to other views, just invoke a simple method when button is clicked.

The script looks like:

```
<script>
   function SubmitClick () {
        var pid = $(this).data('personid');
        var sid = $(this).data('surveyid');
        var url = '@Url.Action("SubmitSurvey", "Person")';
        $.post(url, { personid: pid, surveyid: sid }, function (data) {
            alert('updated');
        });
    };
</script>
```

The button looks like:

```
  <button class='mybutton' type='button' data-personid="@Model.Item1.Id" data-surveyid="@survey.Id" onclick="javascript:SubmitClick()">Click Me</button>
```

The PersonController method looks like:

```
public void SubmitSurvey(int personId, int surveyId) {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("UPDATING DATABASE");

}
```

The full view **(this is PartialView**):

```
<script>
   function SubmitClick () {
        var pid = $(this).data('personid');
        var sid = $(this).data('surveyid');
        var url = '@Url.Action("SubmitSurvey", "Person")';
        $.post(url, { personid: pid, surveyid: sid }, function (data) {
            alert('updated');
        });
    };
</script>

@using WebApplication2.Models
@model   System.Tuple<Person, List<Survey>>

<hr />
<h1>Surveys</h1>
<input type="button" id="Coll" value="Collapse" onclick="javascript:CollapseDiv()" />
@*<p>
        Number of Surveys: @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.Item2.Count)
    </p>*@

@{int i = 1;}
@foreach (var survey in Model.Item2) {
    using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        <h2>Survey @(i)</h2>
        <p />
        @Html.EditorFor(x => survey.Questions)
        <button class='mybutton' type='button' data-personid="@Model.Item1.Id" data-surveyid="@survey.Id" onclick="javascript:SubmitClick()">Click Me</button>
    }
    i++;
    <hr style="background-color:rgb(126, 126, 126);height: 5px" />
}
<hr />
```

The problem is that when I click the button: [image]

I get runtime error saying that there is no definition of: `"SubmitClick"`.

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, you have jQuery so why are you programming events directly on HTML elements like it's 1999?

Comment: Can you post the entire HTML generated by the view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Associating script with a button in ASP .NET MVC Razor View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559610/associating-script-with-a-button-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-view)

Comment: @ErikPhilips I don't know I tried many ways to solve this. Some of them did not give any outcome(no errors and nothing happen) so the jquery function haven't been invoked. Here I get a message that's something wrong. Could you propose how to fix this, I am really tired of this

Comment: @ErikPhilips I tried that: http://wklej.org/id/1452605/ like Stephen Muecke said but NOTHING happens.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Sorry for duplicate I fighted with it for a long time. Could you refer to my ANSWER here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559610/associating-script-with-a-button-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-view/25574770#25574770

Comment: Are you debugging client side javascript code with visual studio? I will try to use F12 developer toolbar to debug on browser instead. Maybe that'll give you some hint on what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any obvious problems in your code, but given that you're handling this in a sub-optimal way, refactoring your code may solve the problem just by improving the setup.

First, don't embed your scripts directly in the view. I understand that you need to include a URL generated via one of the Razor helpers, but what I'm talking about here is using sections so that your scripts get included in a standard location in the document:

So, in your view:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        // your code here
    </script>
}
```

And then in your layout:

```
    <!-- global scripts like jQuery here --> 
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

This ensures that 1) all your JavaScript goes where it should, right before the closing body tag and 2) all your JavaScript gets run *after* the various global scripts that it will likely depend on (jQuery).

Second, it's usually a bad idea to define things in the global scope, such as you are doing with your `SubmitClick` function. If another script comes along and defines it's own `SubmitClick` function in the global scope, then yours gets hosed or vice versa. Instead, you want to use namespaces or closures.

**Namespace**

```
var MyNamespace = MyNamespace || {};

MyNamespace.SubmitClick = function () {
    ...
}
```

**Closure**

```
(function () {
    // your code here
})();
```

Of course, if you use a closure like this, then you `SubmitClick` function truly won't exist, as it's no longer in the global scope, which brings me to...

Third, don't use the `on*` HTML attributes. It's far better to bind functionality to elements dynamically, for example:

```
(function () {
    $('.mybutton').on('click', function () {
        var pid = $(this).data('personid');
        var sid = $(this).data('surveyid');
        var url = '@Url.Action("SubmitSurvey", "Person")';
        $.post(url, { personid: pid, surveyid: sid }, function (data) {
            alert('updated');
        });
    });
})();
```

Now, you've got zero scope pollution and behavior is bound where behavior is defined, instead of tightly-coupling your HTML and JavaScript.